# Problem visualizing the rating value inside a view

Tags: views, rating

I'm using the [Voting API](http://drupal.org/project/votingapi) and [Vote Up/Down](http://drupal.org/project/vote_up_down) modules. My problem is that I can't display the vote result in a view.

What I've done is creating a relationship ("Node: Vote results") and used "Vote results: value" as field.

I'm getting a vote counter, but it always shows zero, even if I am voting inside a node. By the way, inside a node the vote counter is displayed correctly.

Comment: Did you verify that using the development snapshot of the modules the problem is still present? Using the development snapshot of Views, I noticed that there are some issues, part of which are caused by Views (even if they are a minority), and part of which are caused by the other modules that didn't update their Views integration code.

Comment: I just found my issue. In my relationship for Node: Vote Results I had not chosen an aggregation function. I chose Total Score and it fixed it. I don't remember doing this before so I dont know if something changed between versions but anyway, that was my issue.